# How do I disable exp/lib generation when building an exe?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, win32ole

I realize this is probably caused by some _dllexport() somewhere, not in my code but in some third-party piece. (Qt, Boost, OpenSG, ...)

Is there a simple linker option to disable this? I've searched but not found anywhere.

Comment: Note that it can also be caused by CUDA libraries and any other GPU libraries to demand high-performance GPU from the OS -- examples are `AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance`, `NvOptimusEnablement` `NvOptimusEnablementCuda`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To disable generation of `.lib` use `/NOIMPLIB` linker switch.
- To disable generation of `.exp` files use `/NOEXP` linker switch.

Comment: There is no switches like this mentioned in the documentation for the linker. Where in the world you even got this undocumented switches?

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer I ran `link /?` from the command line?

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, no, because the relevant #pragma's override the linker settings.

Answer (score -4):

I suggest you make sure that you have different folders for intermediate files and output files.

I use to setup the projects this way (project properties/general configuration page):

```
Output Directory = $(SolutionDir)\Build\$(ConfigurationName)
Intermediate Directory = $(SolutionDir)\Build\$(ConfigurationName)\$(ProjectName)
```

Comment: I have that. The exp/lib are output files. (makes good sense for dlls)